# Mongo DB query shell to Mongo driver Builders

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-query, mongodb-.net-driver

I have some issues to convert a shell based query to a mongo driver builder equivalent.

I have the following shell script that works

```
[
  {
    $match:
      /**
       * query: The query in MQL.
       */
      {
        _id: ObjectId("64c76edfeb2dd2291a501f88"),
      },
  },
   {
     $unset: [
       "_id",
       "deleted",
       "createdAt",
       "tenantId",
     ],
   },
  {
    $lookup:
      /**
       * from: The target collection.
       * localField: The local join field.
       * foreignField: The target join field.
       * as: The name for the results.
       * pipeline: Optional pipeline to run on the foreign collection.
       * let: Optional variables to use in the pipeline field stages.
       */
      {
        from: "User",
        localField: "usersId",
        foreignField: "_id",
        as: "result",
      },
  },
  {
    $unset: ["usersId", "name"],
  },
  {
    $unwind: {
      path: "$result",
      preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: false,
    },
  },
  {
    $set:
      /**
       * field: The field name
       * expression: The expression.
       */
      {
        usersId: null,
        _id: "$result._id",
        createdAt: "$result.createdAt",
        deleted: "$result.deleted",
        name: "$result.name",
        surname: "$result.surname",
        email: "$result.email",
        birthDate: "$result.birthDate",
        tenants: "$result.tenants",
        roles: "$result.roles",
      },
  },
]
```

I have tried to write the following driver builder :

```
//GetUsersByWorkspaceQuery 
            var pipeline = PipelineDefinition<Workspace, User>.Create(new IPipelineStageDefinition[] {

              PipelineStageDefinitionBuilder.Match(Builders<Workspace>.Filter.ElemMatch(w => w.Id, workspaceId)),

              PipelineStageDefinitionBuilder.Lookup<Workspace, User, User>(foreignCollection: _database.GetCollection<User>(nameof(User)),
                   localField: a => a.UsersId,
                   foreignField: b => b.Id,
                   @as: c => "$result"),

              PipelineStageDefinitionBuilder.Unwind<User>("result") 

 var result = await _database.GetCollection<Workspace>(nameof(Workspace)).Aggregate(pipeline).ToListAsync();
```

but I have a runtime exception.

```
The output type to the last stage was expected to be Domain.Entities.User, but was MongoDB.Bson.BsonDocument. (Parameter 'stages')
```

Also, I don't find the methods set/unset i am using in shell in driver builder

What is the problem? , how should I proceed?

thanks

i expect building a mongo driver builder having the same result i have with the shell query

here is request entities
https://www.noelshack.com/2023-31-3-1690964795-sheme-mongo.png
[request entities](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TGndW.png)

Comment: Would be great if you can provide the sample data and model classes. And also your `pipeline` seems incomplete. Based on my experience, you should specify the output type for the `Unwind` method, without specifying the output type by default it will return as `BsonDocument` type. `PipelineStageDefinitionBuilder.Unwind<User, /* Output model type */>("result") `